# Ubuntu stuck on black screen with blinking cursor after install

Tags: boot, 18.04, intel-graphics, 20.04

I formatted my laptop to install Ubuntu 20.4. The laptop is ASUS with NVIDIA GEFORCE 960M.
The installation was successful and after rebooting to complete installation, it gets stuck on the blank screen with the blinking cursor (just after the ASUS logo).

Now I understand that this is an issue with the graphic card drivers, but I am not being able to resolve it. Most of the answers I looked at, suggests to set `nouveau.modeset=0`

But this requires the GRUB menu to show when booting, but the GRUB menu is not displayed in my case, because I have no dual boot.

I saw that this can be enabled in /etc/default/grub file, but I cannot boot the system at all so I can't do that.

Holding the shift does not show the GRUB when booting (both left and right shift), also ESC key shows the booting menu (the one to select from which drive you boot), not the GRUB menu.

I also gave it a try with 18.04, the issue is the same.

Any help would be really appreciated! My work has frozen because of this issue.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it